# Number of or numbers of

Tags: numbers

I am not sure if this sentence should have numbers of or number of. Here is the sentence "Right now, there are some impressive statistics on the numbers of women entrepreneurs in the US."

Comment: The women may be numerous, but the number is only one number.

Comment: The group is considered as a whole, so there is only one number involved.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be surprised to hear one more expert than myself tell you that either one is correct. I believe the singular is more commonly used there.

Comment: Your belief is convincingly confirmed by [this NGram usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=statistics+on+the+numbers+of%2Cstatistics+on+the+number+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstatistics%20on%20the%20numbers%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstatistics%20on%20the%20number%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I just like the idea that your *one more expert than myself* could be parsed as either ***another** expert (besides myself)*, OR *someone who is more expert **than me***.

Comment: Hello, Elliot. Thanks for visiting ELU. Please visit the Help Center to see what is considered a good answer here. Answers lacking reasonable supporting evidence are not considered to be so, as they come across as mere personal opinion (and may be so).